# What should be the .yaml structure for the class with the following schema

Tags: java, parsing, yaml

I have a java class which is being used for setting the objects after reading .yml file. I am stuck at a point where I am not able to set the values in the .yml file. Below is class representation. The mappings is a List and again that there are two key-value pairs. Offices is the list of string and assignment is just a string.

```
public class System {

    public Employee employee;

    public List<Mapping> mappings;


    public System(Employee emplyoee, List<Mapping> mappings) {
        super();
        this.employee = employee;
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setSankalp(Employee sankalp) {
        this.employee = sankalp;
    }

    public List<Mapping> getMappings() {
        return mappings;
    }

    public void setMappings(List<Mapping> mappings) {
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    public static class Employee {

        public String name;
        public String work;


        public Employee(String name, String work) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.work = work;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getWork() {
            return work;
        }
        public void setWork(String work) {
            this.work = work;
        }
    }

    public static class Mapping {

        public String assignment;
        public List<String> offices;


        public Mapping(String assignment, List<String> offices) {
            super();
            this.assignment= assignment;
            this.offices= offices;
        }
        public String getAssignment() {
            return assignment;
        }
        public void setAssignment(String assignment) {
            this.assignment= assignment;
        }
        public List<String> getOffices() {
            return offices;
        }
        public void setOffices(List<String> offices) {
            this.offices= offices;
        }
    }
}

public class SystemWrapper {
    public System system;

    public SystemWrapper(System system) {
        super();
        this.system = system;
    }

    public System getSystem() {
        return system;
    }

    public void setSystem(System system) {
        this.system = system;
    }
}
```

What can be the structure of the .yaml? I am trying with the following .yaml which is not working at all.

```
system:
 employee:
  name: "andy"
  work: "eng"
 mappings:
  - offices: ["new york", "dc"]
    assignment: "full time"
```

Comment: Be specific with both "trying" (code) and "not working" (error message or incorrect behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
system:
 employee:
  name: "andy"
  work: "eng"
 mappings:
   -mapping:
     offices: ["new york", "dc"]
     assignment: "full time"
   -mapping:
     offices: ["yorkshire", "dc"]
     assignment: "part time"
```

In your code `mappings` is a List of `Mapping` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your yaml mapping looks OK. I tried it in example Spring application and it worked. What I had to change was removing constructor from classes and leave defaults. So try to remove this:

```java
public System(Employee emplyoee, List<Mapping> mappings) {
...
public Mapping(String assignment, List<String> offices) {
...
public Employee(String name, String work) {
...
public SystemWrapper(System system) {
```

Also you have misspelled in `setEmployee`:

```java
public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setSankalp(Employee sankalp) {
    this.employee = sankalp;
}
```

Additionally [in this blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml) you can read more about parsing yaml and test different approaches.